# If I mutate onto a creature that will be exiled later, will it still be exiled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering if I played [Wake to Slaughter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wake%20to%20Slaughter) and then mutated on top of that card, would the creature still be exiled at the end step?

Answer (score 3):

You will exile the merged creature at the end of turn, losing both the original creature and the mutate card you cast on it.

From the rulings listed [here](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Mutate):

> The merged creature is the same creature it was before the merge

So mutating it doesn’t have any effect on the delayed triggered ability that was set up.